# Boost Adapter class to convert matrix to to graph

Tags: c++, boost-graph

I need to find out the shortest path between two nodes in a 2D array. For that i would like to use boost graph library. But the boost graph library accepts graph as input. So i need to convert 2D array to graph. I have also heard that an adapter class matrix to graph can be used for this purpose. But when i went through that i couldn't clearly understand that too. Also i couldn't find any examples for that. So could anyone please give me a sample code regarding how to use that adapter code for converting matrix to graph?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1M7a0s%241) piece of code linked in the comment to [Extract the adjacency matrix from a BGL graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545877/extract-the-adjacency-matrix-from-a-bgl-graph).

There doesn't seem to be an easier way than just iterating your matrix and adding edges to a graph for now.

```
for(i = 0; i < nrows; ++i)
    for(j = 0; j < ncols; ++j)  //of course in a graph nrows should equal ncols.
        if(matrix[i][j] != 0){
            add_edge(i,j,g);
        }
```

Provided you have a vecS vertex graph (integer vertex descriptors).

The [matrix adapter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/boost/graph/matrix_as_graph.hpp) class is undocumented in boost for now. After looking at the implementation and [this mailing list post](http://lists.boost.org/ublas/2010/03/4070.php) it seems that this is meant to work with the [boost::numeric::ublas::mapped_matrix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/html/classboost_1_1numeric_1_1ublas_1_1mapped__matrix.html) judging by the reference to the `nnz` method (number of non-zero elements).

Though not stated in the matrix adapter, the [vector adapter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/boost/graph/vector_as_graph.hpp) and [leda adapter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/boost/graph/leda_graph.hpp), with the same authors states:

"This module requires the C++ compiler to support partial
  specialization for the graph_traits class, so this is not portable
  to VC++."

Thus even if you get these undocumented adapters to work they will not compile using VC++.

You will just have to iterate your matrix and add the edges by hand (as far as I know).