# How Can I Read in a Graph to an Adjacency Matrix In the Boost Graph Library?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, adjacency-matrix, boost-graph

In the boost graph library, there are two popular functions to read in graphs from a file:
[`boost::read_graphviz()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/graph/doc/read_graphviz.html), and [`boost::read_graphml()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/graph/doc/read_graphml.html), for the [GraphViz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz) and the [GraphML format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphML), respectively.

Now both read generically to any type of `boost::adjacency_list<...>`, as they are models of the [Mutable Graph](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/graph/doc/MutableGraph.html) concept:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphml.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>

template <typename GraphType>
GraphType load(std::string filename, std::string format) {

    GraphType g(0);

    std::ifstream t(filename.c_str());
    boost::dynamic_property dp(boost::ignore_other_properties);

    if (format == "graphml")
        boost::read_graphml(t, g, dp);
    else
        boost::read_graphviz(t, g, dp);

    return g;
}
```

If you were to test

```
load<boost::adjacency_matrix<boost::undirectedS> >("my_file.gv", "graphviz");
```

you might get something like

```
Assertion failed: (false), function add_vertex, file /usr/local/include/boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp, line 966.
Abort trap: 6
```

So how can I include the possibility to read to a `boost::adjacency_matrix<...>`, preferably without having to copy the graph from an intermediate adjacency list, as explained [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545877) (the graph may be really large).

What I don't understand is, that for copying, the (copy target) graph [apparently](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/graph/doc/copy_graph.html) *also* has to be a Mutable Graph, so how can we then copy to an adjacency matrix? And not *read* into one?

Thanks for any help!

### Note

The `boost/graph/graphml.hpp` library is not header-only and needs to be linked against, for example by appending `-lboost_graph` when compiling/linking directly from the CLI, as in

```sh
g++ -lboost_graph my_file.cc
```

Comment: "as they are derived from the Mutable Graph concept" should read "as they are models of the Mutable Graph concept" which is a notably different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regarding `copy_graph`

> What I don't understand is, that for copying, the (copy target) graph apparently also has to be a Mutable Graph, so how can we then copy to an adjacency matrix? And not read into one?

I agree. That doesn't make sense. For all it appears the `copy_graph` should not work **or** the documented concept requirement is out-of-date.

Perhaps it was always over-constrained, or specializations have been added specifically for `adjacency_matrix`.

A cursory glance tells that it might have been over-constrained since clearly no specializations/overloads exist for adjacency_matrix.

Before we test, let's look at the assertion.

### Regarding the Assertion

The assert stems here:

```
template < typename D, typename VP, typename EP, typename GP, typename A >
inline typename adjacency_matrix< D, VP, EP, GP, A >::vertex_descriptor
add_vertex(adjacency_matrix< D, VP, EP, GP, A >& g)
{
    // UNDER CONSTRUCTION
    BOOST_ASSERT(false);
    return *vertices(g).first;
}
```

As you can see this was already an area where more flexibility was being planned. It does seem likely that if you reserve enough space, you might be able to read the graph.

The same might be what already powers `copy_graph` (in that `add_vertex` is just avoided when the capacity already suffices; even though `add_vertex` is still technically (*conceptually*) required, it may not always be.

### Testing The Hypotheses

Let's put it to the test. See whether we can actually copy from adjacency list into a matrix:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/copy.hpp>
using boost::vecS;
using D = boost::undirectedS¹;
using L = boost::adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, D>;
using M = boost::adjacency_matrix<D>;

int main() {
    { L list(0); M matrix(20); copy_graph(matrix, list);   } // okay
    { L list(0); M matrix(20); copy_graph(list,   matrix); } // okay
    { L list(1); M matrix(1);  copy_graph(list,   matrix); } // ASSERTS
    { L list(1); M matrix(20); copy_graph(list,   matrix); } // ASSERTS
}
```

(*¹ The directionality doesn't actually make a difference, I tested*)

There's the answer to our riddle. We **can't** actually copy.

It does compile but it doesn't run without assertion.

Now, you are probably thinking you can `#define NDEBUG` and silence the assertion. However, looking at the code above it's clear that you **cannot** expect this to work, because it will always return vertex `0`:

[Sad Trombone](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3673256947fd4e9c):

```
#define NDEBUG
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
using boost::vecS;
using D = boost::undirectedS;
using L = boost::adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, D>;
using M = boost::adjacency_matrix<D>;

int main() {
    L list(5);
    M matrix(10);

    add_edge(1, 4, list);
    add_edge(3, 1, list);

    copy_graph(list, matrix);

    print_graph(list, std::cout << "\nlist:");
    print_graph(matrix, std::cout << "\nmatrix:");
}
```

Prints

```
list:0 --> 
1 --> 4 
2 --> 
3 --> 1 
4 --> 

matrix:0 --> 0 
1 --> 
2 --> 
3 --> 
4 -->
```

That's cleary not correct, though it is what you'd expect from reading the code.

### Closing Words

It could be easier to just write some parsing code manually. If you must you might read into a heavily optimized adjacency list first. For example you could memory map it completely.

If `boost::adjacency_list` doesn't let you, you can consider providing your own datastructures modeling the Mutable Graph concept. That may sound daunting, but it's actually less work than you might expect:

- [What is needed to use BGL algorithms on existing data structures ( edges and vertices as vector<Object *>)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56193619/what-is-needed-to-use-bgl-algorithms-on-existing-data-structures-edges-and-ver)
- a followup that makes it work with a lot more algorithms: [What is required for a custom BGL graph to work with topological sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66352055/what-is-required-for-a-custom-bgl-graph-to-work-with-topological-sort/66352925#66352925)
- on storing complex datastructures in mapped memory I have lots of answers using Boost Interprocess

To be frank, those answers are less complex than the [bonus section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66975545/how-do-i-generically-access-the-boost-graph-bundled-properties/66976686#comment118393259_66976686) I just made on your other question. Do give them a read for inspiration (starting with the first one)